# Spring Batch - Use the application's Transaction Manager

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job as part of an application. The application already has a TransactionManager and when I use the @EnableBatchProcessing Spring Batch also tries to create a TransactionManager in the SimpleBatchConfiguration. I can't use the override bean property here as I need to use the application's TransactionManager. I was thinking creating a Custom annotation like the @EnableBatchProcessing and use a custom configuration which does not create a TransactionManager. Is there a better way to set or configure SpringBatch to use the existing application's TransactionManager and not create it's own?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816, which was fixed in v5.0.0-M1.

> Is there a better way to set or configure SpringBatch to use the existing application's TransactionManager and not create it's own?

Unless you remove the usage of `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you won't be able to prevent the exposure of the transaction manager bean because of the `@Bean` annotation on `org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration#transactionManager`.

That said, you can provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` and override `getTransactionManager` to instruct Spring Batch to use a custom transaction manager. This is mentioned in documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig).

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud! I did override the BatchConfigurer but I have no control over the Bean creation both in spring batch and my application framework. Both transaction managers have the bean name transactionManager. So I'll have to remove the @EnableBatchProcessing and custom configure all factories (StepBuilder and JobBuilder)